FlutterでRunするとEntrypoint isn't within the current projectというエラーが出てしまう
久しぶりにFlutter Runをしようとしたところ、上記のエラーが出て動作テストができません。
前提としてFlutter doctorは全てOKです。
ここの対処方法を試しましたが、改善できません。
ネットで対処方法を調べても、上記リンクと同じような対処方法しか出てこなく、詰んでいます。
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Flutter 3.19.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 54e66469a9 (10 days ago) • 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
Engine • revision c4cd48e186
Tools • Dart 3.3.4 • DevTools 2.31.1
他に確認事項があれば、質問いただければ追記いたします。
対処方法をご教授いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

開発環境のホストOSのバージョンも記載してください。次のURLのコメントに記載されている方法は試しましたか？ No 'Flutter' menu option on android module · Issue #3873 · flutter/flutter-intellij · GitHub
